# Python multiprocess pool.map takes too long for initialization

Tags: python, multiprocess

```
%%time
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
from multiprocessing import Pool


def get_id(x):
    return x['motor_id']

def parallel_load(df, get_id):
    print('parallel_load: ', datetime.now())
    return df.apply(lambda x: get_id(x), axis=1)

def parallel_df(df, func, n_cores):
    print('start: ', datetime.now())
    df_split = np.array_split(df, n_cores)
    print('splitted: ', datetime.now())
    pool = Pool(n_cores)
#     df = pd.concat(pool.map(func, df_split))
    s = datetime.now()
    print('pool start: {}'.format(s))
    data = pool.map(func, df_split)
    print('pool end: {}, {}s'.format(datetime.now(), (datetime.now() - s).seconds))
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
    print('pool join: {}s'.format((datetime.now() - s).seconds))
    
    return data

new_func = partial(
    parallel_load, get_id=get_id
)

ndf = pd.DataFrame({'motor_id': np.arange(10000)})
parallel_df(ndf, new_func, 4)
```

With the sample code above,
I get this result

```
start:  2024-01-02 16:58:09.390751
splitted:  2024-01-02 16:58:09.391897
parallel_load:  parallel_load: parallel_load: parallel_load: parallel_load:  parallel_load: 2024-01-02 16:58:12.453533parallel_load:  parallel_load: 2024-01-02 16:58:12.456901parallel_load: parallel_load:   

2024-01-02 16:58:12.456053  2024-01-02 16:58:12.4578302024-01-02 16:58:12.457674   2024-01-02 16:58:12.457189

2024-01-02 16:58:12.457663

2024-01-02 16:58:12.4583492024-01-02 16:58:12.458657
2024-01-02 16:58:12.457537


pool start: 2024-01-02 16:58:12.448087
pool end: 2024-01-02 16:58:12.504469, 0s
pool join: 0s
CPU times: user 52.5 ms, sys: 3.48 s, total: 3.53 s
Wall time: 3.39 s
```

As you can see, it seems like it takes about 3 seconds to start the actual code for each process after pool.map was calling.

check the time between "splitted" and "parallel_load"

Is there a way to shorten this time?
It seems like pool.map is not good for using small works like this; since getting to start takes too much time compare to the actual processing time.

Comment: Sending a large amount of data to a different process is slow. You are better off doing everything in the same process.

Comment: multiprocessing has to serialize an send the data to the other processes.  You could try threads with `multiprocessing.dummy` or you could build a multiprocessing shared object (e.g. `Array`) so the data doesn't need to be copied.

Comment: @MikeMcKerns Could you please provide the sample code about 5 to 10 lines to add on the example code?

Comment: @IsaacSim I attempted to replicate your issue, but the code you posted didn't generate that output. After altering your code to get it to a runnable state, it took only 0.3 seconds on my machine, which could be improved if necessary. Can you update your question with the code you actually ran and the output it generates?

Comment: @BitsAreNumbersToo The sample code was tested before I uploaded. And your 0.3 second is already big enough(although not as much as I tested), which I priorly expected the distribution and initialization of cpu cores for parallel working is much much less than that.